# Ionic 2 - Full Screen Issue on Android and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, ionic2

I have an ionic 2 app which contains sections like Google Maps, html5 YouTube, Video, and Mp4 Video. Full Screen Control on all of them is not working and giving blank page. This is the YouTube example. I tried allowfullscreen="" or allowfullscreen="true" but still no luck. I tried to research but couldn't find a solution.

```
    <iframe width="80%" height="600" [src]='CurrentResource.YoutubeIdURL'
        frameborder="0" 
        allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
        mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" 
        msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" 
        oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" 
        webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen">
    </iframe>
```